# why saveOrUpdate doesn't insert note in database when it executes if I use save

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have question about hibernate strange behaviour.

I have so code:

```
Prepod prepod = new Prepod();
        prepod.setId(1l);
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setAge(12l);
        student.setName("name");
        student.setId(1l);
        prepod.getStudents().add(student);
        student.getPrepods().add(prepod);

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.saveOrUpdate(prepod);
        session.saveOrUpdate(student);


        session.getTransaction().commit();
```

hibernate says me:

```
Hibernate: update Student set age=?, name=? where id=?
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3016)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2918)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3247)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1214)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:403)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at logic.Main.main(Main.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

but if I use

```
    session.save(prepod);
    session.save(student);
```

I see:

```
Hibernate: select max(id) from prepod
Hibernate: select max(id) from Student
Hibernate: insert into prepod (id) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into Student (age, name, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into prepod_Student (prepods_id, students_id) values (?, ?)
```

It is good behavior for me.

Can you explain why it works so?

Before I think that saveOrUpdate automatically select save or update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in distinguishing if the object exists in DB or not.

The ID of objects `Prepod` and `Student` is obviously set to `generator="increment"` *(that's why we see the `Select Max(id)` statements)*. And most likely the `unsaved-value` is left to be the default: 0.

That means that Hibernate, treats the Prepod instance to be new/transient in case, that the ID is == 0. But in your code you set the id:  `student.setAge(12l);`

So, the Object is not transient any more (from perspective of the Hibernate). It seems that it is the existing, already persisted object.

So if the `SaveOrUpdate` is called, Hibernate deicdes to use `UPDATE` statement, because the object seems to be not transient.

How to solve it? Do **not** set the ID your self. Just rely on the `generator="increment"`. In that case the object will be transient (with the default id == 0) and Hibernate will work as you expect

Comment: But in your code you set the id: student.setAge(12l); -  error here